# VSCode add .js extension on import autocomplete

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, visual-studio-code

I am using **VSCode** and **JavaScript ES6 Modules**.

If I **autocomplete** an **import** like this `import * as test from './test'`
the **.js** ending on `./test` is **missing** and I have to add it **manually**.

Is there a setting to **automatically add the extension**?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Add this to your settings.json

```
"javascript.preferences.importModuleSpecifierEnding": "js",
"typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifierEnding": "js",
```

Or in the Settings UI

[image: auto imports js]

Comment: i have tried that but it doesnt work
"javascript.preferences.importModuleSpecifierEnding": "js"
"typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifierEnding": "js"

Comment: I think there is an issue when it comes to typescript https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39155

Comment: Does not work for me either. Anyone knows a workaround?

Comment: @CanonicEpicure did you check the option is set properly? https://i.imgur.com/y5fIvmw.png

Comment: @tHeSiD of course, set to `js` for both JavaScript and TypeScript

Comment: doesn't work for me